# Unable to install windowsServerCore Container Image

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, windows-container, docker-aws

I am trying to install windowsServercore images on my WIndows 2016 server using below command.

```
Install-containerImage WindowsServerCore
```

while running it got below error message.

```
Install-ContainerOSImage : The term 'Install-ContainerOSImage' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Found there is a work around from article

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc571caf-af13-45ed-a021-cfcfcf532645/the-term-installcontainerosimage-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet-on-build-build-14385?forum=windowscontainers

While running the commands from the new article, getting different error message.

```
docker load -i nanoserver.tar.gz

58684737b3d1: Loading layer [==================================================>] 358.4 MB/358.4 MB
re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessBaseLayer C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\dc41572502daedc9c628b56d1f369
ee804e901159b053d5e082e31e339ae822d: A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the
 current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file.
```

My system time is correct and i am running Windows 2016 server on AWS.

Any help to fix this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get that cmdlet from and what are you trying to do? Why not using normal `docker` commands.

Answer (score 3):

You can use bellow command to pull the image to your docker host which is windows server 2016:

*docker pull microsoft/windowsservercore*

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command:

```
docker run -t -i mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809
```

This will load Nano Server from the official Microsoft DockerHub repository:

https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-nanoserver